# What is the difference between ForAll and Select in PLINQ

Tags: .net, performance, linq, ironpython, plinq

In the [intro to PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq), the docs seem to show two different ways of getting data back from a process unordered.  In one case, AsParallel can be used with Unsorted and the Select or SelectMany method.  SelectMany says it

> Projects in parallel each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable
>   and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So to get a return list from a function, I call it like this:

```
def genGraph(node,constData):
    #do something
    return (constData+1,constData+2,constData+3)

newGraph = Graph.AsParallel().SelectMany(lambda node: genGraph(node,constData) ).ToList()
```

The other way would be using ForAll and a `ConcurrentBag` that is added to, and nothing returned.

> For faster query execution when order preservation is not required and
>   when the processing of the results can itself be parallelized, use the
>   ForAll method to execute a PLINQ query.

```
def genGraph(node,constData,newGraph):
    #do something
    newGraph.Add(constData+1,constData+2,constData+3)

newGraph = Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[type((0,0,0))]()
Graph.AsParallel().ForAll(lambda node: genGraph(node,constData,newGraph) )
```

So the first one says it projects in parallel to an IEnumerable, and the second one says it is faster when processing can be parallelized.  It sounds to me the same thing. In my code, it currently runs the same amount of time as well, but I am wondering if there is some other case I am not understanding.

Comment: This is probably more of a .NET than an IronPython question. Without knowing what your actual workload/chunks of work look like it will be hard to say if there are any practical differences in the two approaches. There are many scenarios that can be solved both ways without any noticeable change in performance and I suspect that the involvement of the DLR/IronPython will make it hard to construct cases where there is a significant performance difference.

Comment: The second quote also continues with "ForAll does not perform this final merge step.", which is a clue of difference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/merge-options-in-plinq.

Comment: @Rob So if you need to do something a variable and get it back, they are the same?